# React Native - can it do these things efficiently?

Tags: react-native

We use React/Redux for our web-based app in production, and it works really-really well. We've been curious about React Native, and have a few quick questions. We're looking for facts only, not opinions, and not interested in starting a debate.

In order to build our app, we would need the following:

1. push notifications - I see a few projects on github, but does anyone have a robust solution running in production for a real app?
2. background processing - what happens when this app isn't running in the foreground (does background processing run similarly as other native apps, i.e. can I go to the Apple Setting app and disable the background worker threads?
3. web sockets - again, I've seen a few projects on github with experimental results, and yes I've heard that "this is trivial to implement, you just have to write a poly-fill". What I want is a drop-in solution, that's well tested.
4. in-app purchases - has anyone connected react native to Apple's in-app purchase system.

Thanks! I realize that react-native is in early beta, but in order for us to build an app efficiently, we need to make sure these basic things are ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Push notifications are included with React Native although the API is not as mature as core APIs like the view system.
2. React Native actually pauses some of its work when the app is backgrounded and background processing has not been a focus yet. You would instead want to delegate work to a dispatch queue. This might work for your use case if the background processing doesn't involve application logic, which you want to keep in JS.
3. WebSockets work reasonably well with React Native. Several contributors have helped build up WebSocket support. Out of your four requirements, I would say that WebSockets are the best supported.
4. There are npm packages like [react-native-in-app-utils](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils) that expose the IAP APIs.